# Accessing Method's parameter of Array within the function body

Tags: c#

I want to access the two array parameters (column and value) of the below method but they underlined and shows "Method name expected" when i hover on them.

```
public static bool saveData(string sql,  Array column, Array value)
    {
        bool success=false;
        try
        {
            Global.cm = new SQLiteCommand() { 
                Connection = cn,
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                CommandText = sql

            };
            for (int t = 0; t <= column.Length - 1; t++)
            {
                
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(**column**(t).ToString(), **value**(t)); // The column and value indicates error message -- "Method name expected"
            }
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cm.Dispose();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Operation Status");
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited this line...

```
public static bool saveData(string sql,  Array column, Array value)
```

to

```
public static bool saveData(string sql,  string[] column, string[] value)
```

and this line...

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(column[t].ToString(), value[t]);
```

to

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(column[t].ToString(), value[t]);
```

and it works.

Comment: Your 2 lines after `and this line...` are the same?!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
public static bool saveData(string sql,  Array column, Array value)
{
    bool success=false;
    try
    {
        Global.cm = new SQLiteCommand() { 
            Connection = cn,
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            CommandText = sql

        };
        for (int t = 0; t <= column.Length - 1; t++)
        {    
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(column[t].ToString(), value[t]);
        }
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cm.Dispose();
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Operation Status");
    }
    return success;
}
```